# get the window size in a DrawableGameComponent in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I have an `Avatar` object inherited from `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.DrawableGameComponent`

I try to get the window's dimension in the overrided method `Update` of my `Avatar`.
But i don't find any methods to get the width and the height of the window.

the method `GraphicsDeviceManager.DefaultBackBufferHeight` doesn't work so far.

my constructor :

```
    public Avatar(Game game)
        : base(game)
    {
        // TODO: Construct any child components here
    }
```

Comment: If you are after the size of the rendering area, you generally want the size of the *viewport*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`game.Window`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game_members.aspx) for the Window. The [`GameWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamewindow_members.aspx) class has the `ClientBounds` member you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the width and height of the active `Viewport` with these properties.

```
this.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width
this.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height
```

By default, the active `Viewport` will be the entire window.